# Is there a way to limit the maximum memory size of a ASP.NET 3.5 process?

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory

I have several ASP Dot.Net web sites, and I wish to limit their maximum memory. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter apllication pool settings and set **Private Memory Limit (KB)** and **Virtual Memory Limit (KB)**, to what ever memory you want to limit your application with. When that quota is reached the application pool will recycle.

Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f4e96b27-189c-491f-a941-fec28f5cead1.mspx?mfr=true) on how to change the two